# database items as bootstrap 4 cards

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

as the title say I'm working on a product draft the which the products are inserted into an accordion to collapse. the problem is I used PHP to loop for each database row insert a new product card inside the collapsable accordion, but the align is not as I wanted it is most to be side by side until there's no space to draw another product card and then escape for the next line.

```html
 <html>
  <head><title>Project</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><!-- Bootstrap CDN Font-awesome -->
  
  </head>
  <body>
  
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->

  <div class="card ProfileContent">
    <div class="card-body">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="direction:RTL;">
     <li class="nav-item" style="font-family:hana !important;">
      <a href="#about" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x"></i></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item" style="font-family:hana !important;">
      <a href="#drafts" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-paperclip fa-3x"></i></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item" style="font-family:hana !important;">
      <a href="#connect" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-address-book fa-3x"></i></a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" style="font-family:hana !important; text-align: right;">
       <div id="about" class="tab-pane fade">
         <h3>معلومات عن الشركة</h3>
         <p>حساب المسؤول (الدعم الفني)</p>
       </div>
       <div id="drafts" class="tab-pane in active">
         <h3>المنتجات</h3>
      <p>درفتات الشركة هنا</p>
      <div id="accordianId" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="section1HeaderId">
         <h5 class="mb-0">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordianId" href="#section1ContentId" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="section1ContentId">
Draft number 1
        </a>
         </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="section1ContentId" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="section1HeaderId">
         <div class="card-body">
          <?
          foreach($DRTitems as $product)
          {?>
          <div class="card" style="width:268px; height:auto;">
            <img class="card-img-top" style="width:260px; height:220px;" src="..\upload\panadol.png"></img>
           <div class="card-title" style="font-family:hana !important; font-size: 34px !important; color:black !important; text-align:center !important;">
            <!-- Prodcut name -->إسم الدواء
           </div>
           <div class="card-text ml-3" style="color:black !important; text-align:left !important;">
            التركيبة الكيميائية
           </div><br><br>
           <form action="#" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="form-group d-flex flex-fill">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control ml-4" style="width:90px !important;"name="" id="" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="الكمية" required>
             </div>
             <div class="options d-flex flex-fill">
                      <select class="custom-select" style="width:140px" required>
                          <option selected>حجم العبوة</option>
                           <?
                           $optionCounter = 1;
                           foreach($productdosageform as $dosageform){
                               echo'<option value="'.$optionCounter.'">'.$dosageForm['dosageform'].'</option>';
                                $optionCounter = ++$optionCounter;
                             }?>
                         </select>
               </div>
            </div>
            <center>
            <div class="form-group d-flex flex-fill">
             <label for="price" Style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif !important; font-size:28px !important; color:lightgreen! important; position: relative; left:90px;">30LYD</label>
            </div>
            </center>
            <div class="form-group">
             <center>
             <input type="submit" value="إضافة للسلة" class="btn btn-success" style="font-family:hana; text-align:center; width:180px;">
             </center>    
            </div>
           </form>
          </div><?}?>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
       <div id="connect" class="tab-pane fade">
         <h3>الاتصال</h3>
         <p>معلومات الاتصال مع الشركة</p>
       </div>
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

**in action connected to db**
[image: screenshot]

updated :- after using (d-flex justify-content-around) this is what i get 
[image: newscreenshot]

Comment: Use "d-flex justify-content-around" classes with card-body class. That will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
style="display:inline"
```

for them

Comment: @Suraj Rao Thank you for correcting me.. I am new to this community and English is not my mother tounge... I am sorry if my answer was innappropriate..